# Problema con api V2 maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

la consulta sería que no sabria usarlo bien, ya que estoy guiandome por lo que dicen los tutoriales y en SO (en ingles) pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar
tengo los siguientes datos:

**content_locales.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogoLocal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_local" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        class="com.reservamos.MapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReservar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/solicitar_reserva" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LocalActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = getContext();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locales);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    imagenlocal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogoLocal);
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new android.support.v4.app.Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mapview, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    int id;
    id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
    Servicio ser = new Servicio();
    Locales local = new Locales();
    try {
        local = ser.GetLocal(context, id);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    toolbar.setTitle(local.getNombre());
    if (imagenlocal != null){
        byte[] decodeString  = new byte[0];
        try {
            decodeString = Base64.decode(local.getImagen(), Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString,
                0, decodeString.length);
        imagenlocal.setImageBitmap(decodebitmap);
    }
}
```

y el mapa

**MapFragment.java** y **fragment_map.xml**

tomado de http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287

no coloco las clases porque no modifique nada de las clases pertenecientes al tutorial

el problema es que cuando ingreso para que me muestre el mapa, me loguea lo siguiente

> 05-11 01:00:55.262 10220-10242/com.reservamos I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 682293(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 100(1600KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 51MB/67MB, paused 61.646ms total 448.110ms
>
> 05-11 01:00:56.074 10220-10242/com.reservamos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 671925(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 94(1504KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 53MB/67MB, paused 89.349ms total 359.503ms
>
> 05-11 01:00:56.921 10220-10242/com.reservamos I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 707530(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 94(1504KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 56MB/72MB, paused 66.386ms total 467.650ms

y continua con un log parecido, hasta que mato la aplicación directamente.

hay algo que estare haciendo mal?

antes de que me pregunten, si, tengo la api key habilitada para probar y los permisos son los siguientes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<permission
    android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

se agradece cualquier aporte que realicen

Comienzo del log, donde aparentemente podría estar el error

> 05-12 00:21:23.256 25931-25936/com.reservamos I/art: Compiler
>   allocated 4MB to compile void
>   android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) 05-12 00:21:43.932
>   25931-25936/com.reservamos I/art: Do full code cache collection,
>   code=126KB, data=109KB 05-12 00:21:43.933 25931-25936/com.reservamos
>   I/art: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=87KB 05-12
>   00:21:44.075 25931-25936/com.reservamos I/art: Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=121KB, data=97KB 05-12 00:21:44.078
>   25931-25936/com.reservamos I/art: After code cache collection,
>   code=118KB, data=95KB
>       Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB

fragmento en el que podría estar el error, ya que está referenciando algo que no es un error, sino como un mensaje informativo

> 05-12 00:21:20.047 25931-25931/com.reservamos W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.reservamos-2/lib/arm 05-12
>   00:21:20.187 25931-25931/com.reservamos W/art: Before Android 4.1,
>   method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

luego, sigue el primer fagmento que coloque del Garbage Colector

Comment: Esos mensajes en principio son normales, ya que indican que el GC("recolector de basura") está haciendo su trabajo. No te da ningun mensaje de error mas?

Comment: queda clavado en el garbage con pantalla en negro, hasta que mato la ejecución, y el mismo sube groseramente de tamaño limite

Comment: @PabloEzequielFerreyra busca la sección que indique "Caused by" o revisa si encuentras un OutOfMemoryException, el problema probablemente no sea del Mapa, agrega esta información a tu pregunta Pablo.

Comment: bien, ni bien llego lo publico @Jorgesys

Comment: @Jorgesys ahi subi los fragmentos extra que creo que serviran de informacion extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo unico que me valio para poder hacerlo funcional, fue generar este fragment

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LatLng coord;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coord).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(coord).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

y su respectivo layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```